# Intervention Image in laravel 4 create a black image

Tags: php, image-processing, laravel

I'm using Intervention Image in laravel 4 to manage images. When I try to manipulate them I get a black image.

This is the code I use:

```
if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
{
    $name = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('photo')->move(storage_path() . '/uploads/main-photos', $name);
    Image::make(Input::file(storage_path() . '/uploads/main-photos' . $name))->grab(50)->save(storage_path() . '/uploads/main-photos/thumbs/' . $name);
}
```

I get a black image if jpeg and transparent in png.

Comment: I've used Intervention with Laravel with no issues. Do you definitely have GD and anything else Intervention depends upon set up?

Comment: I have an error on my code, instead of

    Image::make(Input::file(storage_path() . '/uploads/main-photos' . $name))

it's

    Image::make(storage_path() . '/uploads/main-photos/' . $name)

problem solved, great library!!!

Comment: By the way, if you're using the global helper functions for paths you can pass your relative appended paths to the function: `Image::make(storage_path('uploads/main-photos/'.$name));`. It may be less readable to you (as what's going on is more magic) but it's something to note.